# Updating JSON into Cache

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am currently building an app which allows you to check for canceled shows on Netflix. To avoid paying for API calls, I am running a 24 hour incremental function which stores the called data into a JSON file. The JSON file is then sent to the front end (React.js) and is supposed to be cached for the user.

A workaround I'm trying is to write the fetched server data to a JSON file in the react/src folder, but I am also struggling to find any good articles on writing to a JSON file from React.

The serviceworkers which React pre-builds have already stored the original JSON file, but refuse to update. I cannot find any good articles on React serviceworkers and only know how to manipulate serviceworkers in base JS. Everything base JS I try fails since React expects different syntax and arguments.

Back End Code
app.js schedule-node function

```
schedule.scheduleJob('* * */23 * *', function(){
  console.log('Daily API call initiated.');
  unirest.get("https://unogs-unogs-v1.p.rapidapi.com/aaapi.cgi?q=get:exp:US&t=ns&st=adv&p=1")
  .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "unogs-unogs-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
  .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", `${keys.RICHARD_UNOGS_KEY}`)
  .end(function (result) {
    console.log(result.status, result.headers);
    //console.log(result.body) to see all data
    let data = JSON.stringify(result.body)
    fs.writeFile('./movieData.json', data)
  });
})
```

app.js sending data to front end

```
app.get('/expiring', (req, res) => {
  res.json(MovieData)
})
```

Front End Code
Component which calls the JSON file

```
componentDidMount() {
        let url = "http://localhost:8080/expiring"
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json)
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state.movies,
                    movies: json
                })
            })
    }
```

serviceWorker.js

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit.......'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed. See https:..........'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

window.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log(event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

I need to update the cached JSON file. I do npm run build since React does not allow service workers otherwise, and in my index.js I have serviceworkers.register. The cache initially updated, but even when cleared does not update with the new JSON file. Any suggestions welcome.

EDIT: Semi-resolved my issue by storing the JSON data sent from the server to the client in a localhost key.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the application architecture, what you actually need is something like this:

1. Server updates apidata.json every 24 hours
2. apidata.json content is served from some server endpoint (doesn't matter if it's /api/apidata.json or something completely different, say /static/24-hour-data.json)
3. Client (React application) requests the data from the server whenever it wants

   - Client can choose to cache the data from the server for some time or not cache it at all

Here the server-side and front-end logic are completely independent. Client doesn't need to know anything about the update schedule of the server and the server doesn't need to know anything about how the client works.

If you want to cache the data in the client to make the application faster and maybe offer offline functionality, you can implement the caching in the client with Local Storage, IndexedDB, or Service Workers. The choise here doesn't really affect the architecture itself – just how you handle the caching. If you use eg. Workbox library in the SW you can easily say that "anything from /static/apidata.json should be cached for 24 hours" and it will do just that.

To make this whole thing work smoothly, you need to configure the Service Worker generation so that the apidata.json file *IS NOT* included in the precached assets in the SW script.